# Grunt CSS minify and Google Fonts

Tags: javascript, html, css, gruntjs, google-font-api

I'm encountering a problem :

I've set up a better workflow mostly with Bower and Grunt. My problem is that now, **after setting up lot of tools to minify, valide, compress, and so on, I have to import a Google Font**.

So basically, I can include it like that : `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700|Vollkorn:400italic,400,700|Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

It's the fastest way to import fonts, I guess, but well, it's another CSS file, so another request to the server, when I try to keep it as low as I can.

So my question is : Is there any way to import *quickly* Google fonts in a Grunt managed project  (with CSS minification and compression) ?

*When I say quickly, I mean : without downloading my fonts as a zip, copying it in my project folder, typing @font-face...)*

Is there a Grunt module that works with google-font-api or something ?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Vist the link and copy paste the result?

Comment: Well, that sound stupid, but it can be a really good solution (better than what I have currently) :)

Comment: Why not download the font and store it on your server like the rest of your css?

Comment: said download of file can be automated with grunt too.

Comment: That can be cool. How to do that ? Existing module ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same type of tool to remove the friction of using bootswatch templates while supporting offline mode.  There is no ready made option that I'm aware of that will automatically parse your css downloading the remote hosted font's and/or following imports like google fonts URLs.  However,https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger gives you the tools you would need to create a customized solution for your project.